# Sorting numbers with c++

Tags: c++

So, I wrote the program that sorts numbers, but whenever I execute it, it adds smallest random number as a first one in "Sorted Numbers" line.

Here's a code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    int numbers[MAX_SIZE];
    int numElements;

    cout << "=============================" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to BubbleSort Program" << endl;
    cout << "=============================" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "How many random numbers do you want us to produce? ";
    cin >> numElements;
    cout << endl;


    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    cout << "=============================" << endl;
    cout << "Random numbers: " << endl;
    cout << "=============================" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){

        numbers[i] = (rand()%100) + 1;
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
        if(i == numElements){
            cout << "i";
        }
    }


    int exchanges;
    int temp;
    int j;

    cout << "=============================" << endl; 
    cout << "Sorted numbers: " << endl;
    cout << "=============================" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numElements; j++){

            if(numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]){

                temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                numbers[j + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "=============================" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output example:

> =============================
>       Welcome to BubbleSort Program
>       =============================
>
> ```
> How many random numbers do you want us to produce? 3
>
> =============================
> Random numbers:
> =============================
> 69
> 8
> 5
> =============================
> Sorted numbers:
> =============================
> -858993460
> 5
> 8
> 69
> =============================
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Soo.. WTF is **-858993460**?!

Comment: It's better if the code you post to Stack Overflow is short as possible.  Replace all the console printing and random number generation with `int numbers[] = {10, 4, 7, 2, 1, 300}`.  This is also a good debugging tactic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in your sorting implementation.  You have an array of size 100 and you add 3 elements.    By going to <= numElements, you are accessing array locations 0, 1, 2, and 3 and thus you are accessing an extra element. Change it to < and you'll be ok.

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing uninitialized memory -

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++) { // <-- no, stop at < -- see above.
  for(int j = 0; j < numElements; j++) // <-- you use j+1 below
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) { // <-- also not initialized.
  for (int j = 0; j < numElements - 1; j++) // <-- like so.
```

Comment: Yes - lucky there's no segfault really.

Comment: a good reason to use `std::vector` in c++ ! You'll get an error instead of a confusing output.

Comment: only if you use `vector::at()` instead of `vector::operator[]`

Comment: @japreiss: I think MSVC will use checked access even for operator[] in debug mode.

Comment: @FredLarson Yeah that wouldn't surprise me.